# How can I figure out what's stepping on my PATH variable?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

In a nutshell: my PATH environment variable is sometimes only available from an elevated session, other times it's fine; how can I find out what's corrupting it for non-admin sessions and prevent it from happening in the future?

For example, I start cmd.exe (or a PowerShell prompt) and try to ping a server and I get the dreaded `'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` message.  If I try the full path to ping, i.e. `c:\windows\system32\ping.exe`, it works just fine.

The problem is that my PATH is empty. To wit:

```
C:\Users\matt>set path
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

C:\Users\matt>path
PATH=(null)
```

If I open an elevated prompt (i.e. right-click and "run as administrator"), everything works fine, and my PATH variable is as expected.

I already know about the 2047 character limit for the path length.  In fact, that was originally my problem, and I've since corrected it.  But I still have intermittent issues with a null path for non-elevated sessions.  Normal sessions sometimes work and sometimes fail, but an elevated session always works.

Killing the explorer.exe process and restarting it via the Task Manager will sometimes reset the path for normal sessions, but other times I have to completely reboot.

This happens several times a week.  I've not found any smoking guns in the event logs, nor even anything suspicious, and it's hard to guess what might be causing the issue since I won't necessarily notice it when it happens.

This computer is a member of a domain, if that makes a difference.

**How can I monitor my PATH variable and detect what process and/or program is modifying it?**  It doesn't seem to be a persistent change, since the registry entry is not affected, but something is clearly ruining it for non-admin sessions on a semi-random basis and I'm out of ideas for further narrowing down the root cause.

Comment: So this is happening intermittently....Is it persisting for a long time or was triggered by some kind of event (e.g. upgrade Windows, DC account update, ...)? Do you have admin rights on that machine (or the DC that controls it)? (in order to check perms)

Comment: When it happens, the problem persists until I "fix" it, either by restarting the explorer.exe process, or rebooting the whole PC when that doesn't work.  I do have admin rights on the box.  I haven't been able to link it to any particular event or upgrade, but that's probably because I can't tell when the problem starts, only when I notice it (i.e. whatever caused it could have happened hours before I try to ping and realize there's a problem).

Comment: Hmm, do you have up2date AV on that system? Cause (at 1st glance) it "smells" like a "virus"

Comment: AV is System Center Endpoint Protection and it's regularly updated.  In fact, it's one of the few things on this box that I can't change (i.e. its settings are managed by our domain admin via group policy, I believe).

Comment: The AV hat's another thing that I missed (it might be blocking itself the access). So, the simple task is here: are you able to reproduce this behavior on a machine without all the _3rdParty_ products (e.g. AV) installed (and here i'm only talking really really local user (do not base on this)  regardless of what the AD admins  )?

Comment: @CristiFati, not sure I follow your last comment.  I can't reproduce the problem on demand on this machine, much less some other.  That's why I'm asking how to monitor the PATH, so I can catch the problem when it happens.

Comment: The env is inherited from the _explorer.exe_ process who is the parent of all processes in the logon session. I'm not sure if there's a way to check when it's being modified (I am not aware of any). The env vars are also stored in the registry (and that can be monitored - e.g. using [_ProcMon_](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx)), but I'm not sure how helpful is that. That's why i suggested the "reversed" approach: to start with a minimal config (with no apps that would trigger this behavior), and then add apps and check when it starts happening.

Comment: Just chiming in I just came across another box that experiences this issue; all of a sudden my environment's variables are cleared out almost completely ( cmd.exe 'path' command returning "PATH=(null)" and 'set' having hardly any values left. 
The process or plugin that is responsible definitely hides itself really quickly, had a script that polled the output of path and dumped a process list when it went null; seemingly nothing of interest in the process list,.. 
This is driving me up the wall, as if a windows box doesn't require enough reboots as it is. :-(